# How to use maven profile based on the IntelliJ profile?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, maven, intellij-idea

I would like to activate maven profile based on the IntelliJ profile I select. I need to use different dependency when running the app locally and when deploying it to server.

I have these two profiles which select correct version of TimesTen, I would like to use "local" profile when testing the app locally in IntelliJ and the "server" profile when building the app.

```xml
<profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>local</id>
            <activation>
                <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
            </activation>
            <properties>
                <org.timesten.version>6</org.timesten.version>
            </properties>
        </profile>
        <profile>
            <id>server</id>
            <properties>
                <org.timesten.version>11</org.timesten.version>
            </properties>
        </profile>
    </profiles>
```

These are my IntelliJ profiles:
[image]

Comment: Spring boot profile is not the same as Maven profile. How exactly do you plan to use the Maven profile in Spring profile? See https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.2.0.M1/reference/html/boot-features-profiles.html and https://www.baeldung.com/spring-profiles to lear about Spring profiles.

Comment: Hi Andrey, basically what I want to do is, that when I select profile in IntelliJ, it will be trigger correct profile in maven profiles. (I would like to have profile1 using some maven configuration and profile2 using another) these configurations are also connected with different spring profiles. Hopefully it makes sense.